# Closed sets flat morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, flatness

Consider the sets $Y_{k}:=\{y\in Y\mid |f^{-1}(y)|\leq k\}$, where
$f:X\to Y$ is a flat quasi-finite morphism between smooth irreducible affine varieties  and $k$ a natural number. Are these  sets $Y_{k}$ closed in $Y$?

Comment: Might be relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/182863/lower-semicontinuity-of-naive-fiber-size

Comment: What does $\lvert f^{-1}(y)\rvert$ mean? Is it the number of elements in the fiber? (in that case, I guess you must suppose that $f$ is finite)

Comment: It denotes the number of elements in the fiber. We may assume $f$ to be quasi-finite, but not necessarily finite.

Comment: If the $\operatorname{deg}(f)=d$ then $Y_{d-1}$ is just the branch locus of $f$ and it is closed as it is equal to $f(\operatorname{Supp}(\Omega_{X/Y}))$. For other $Y_k$ the argument should be similar, I guess.